# How to get the user location from the web app running on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, currentlocation

I am having a problem that when I get user location by using http://freegeoip.net/json, it seems to get the location from where the Heroku server is located.

I used Flask to make the web app.

I uploaded the web app through Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the api docs [here](https://github.com/apilayer/freegeoip#api) you need to pass the ip of the user like  `'http://freegeoip.net/json/%s' % request.remote_addr`. Otherwise it will return the location of the requester, which in your case is your heroku server.